# Validate method not found - Laravel

Tags: laravel

Laravel Framework 5.4.35

**Contacts Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

use App\Mail\ContactEmail;

class ContactsController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('contact.index');
    }

    public function sendContact (Request $request) {

        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required|min:5',
        ]);

        Mail::to('bump@bumpy.net')
                ->send(new ContactEmail($request));

        return redirect('/contact/success');
    }

    public function success() {
        return view('contact.success');
    }
}
```

**The Controller that extends:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

When it goes here:

```
$request->validate([
                'name' => 'required|min:3',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'message' => 'required|min:5',
            ]);
```

**I get this output:**

> (1/1) BadMethodCallException Method validate does not exist

I have the namespace, the classes to be used. The call to the method seems to be ok.

What am I missing?

Care to advise?

If I create a validator instance manually using the  Validator facade.
It seems to validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention your using version 5.4.  The method you're using to validats via the request is only from version 5.5.

So you will need to do it like...

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required|min:5',
]);
```

Hope this helps.  Check out the 5.4v docs rather than the, aster/5.5v
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#validation-quickstart

Laravel 5.4

```
$this->validate($request, [
```

Laravel 5.5

```
$request->validate([
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realise that I was using an older version. From 5.4 to 5.5 seems to happen some broken changes. :( I was not expecting that. How can we deal with those dramatic break changes, if/when one's wish to update to a new version? :(

Comment: @MEM What are those breaking changes you're referring to? I've upgraded several projects from 5.4 to 5.5 without any issues. Are you overriding a bunch of internal methods? [Overall the upgrade process is pretty simple](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade)

Comment: @jfadich It was an assumption. I have `$this->validate()` now, as per Simon answer. Let's say that I wish to upgrade to Laravel 5.5? Because I have  `$this->validate()` instead of `$request->validate(['` wouldn't I receive an error by then?

Comment: @MEM Correct you wouldn't have an error. They added `$request->validate()` but they didn't remove `$this->validate()` so it's not a breaking change.

Comment: @jfadich Ok. Great. Thank you for the additional information.

Comment: @MEM glad to help and yes, it can catch you out sometimes.  But as jfadich mentions it's not if you upgrade, but before upgrading to a later version of laravel, they will always have an Update / upgrade processs :-)

Comment: That's why i prefer to have tests all around application, so that whatever changes we do doesn't break the application.